# change default shell for one application using pam

Tags: shell, login, pam

My default shell is `/bin/bash`, but I would like one application (slim) to use `/bin/sh`, when logging me in.

This is the pam file that slim uses:

```
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1
auth    required        pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-auth
@include common-account

session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so

@include common-session
@include common-password
```

How and where can I override my default shel, so that `/bin/sh` us used instead of my default (as specifiied in `/etc/passwd`).

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to define alias user, something like that

> adduser -u 1000 -g 1000 --no-create-home --no-user-group --non-unique -s /bin/sh --home-dir /home/bash_user sh_user

where user group and group id's are id's of your user.